# Immediately after assigning 0 to an int, the value of the int is 134518533

Tags: c, variables, gdb

Here is output that gdb gives me:

```
(gdb) next 
int i=0; 
(gdb) next 
int j=0; 
(gdb) print i 
$2 = 0 
(gdb) print j 
$3 = 134518533
```

Thanks for any help. This is completely beyond me

Comment: Please show the corresponding source code. Perhaps `j` exists in different scopes?

Comment: Had this code been compiled with any optimisation?

Answer (score 4):

From what you show us of your debugging session you are missing another `next` to have the line

```
j = 0;
```

executed.

So what you see by doing `print j` is the value of `j` **before** the execution of the above line.

The debugging session's output should look like this:

```
(gdb) next 
int i=0; 
(gdb) next 
int j=0; 
(gdb) print i 
$2 = 0 
(gdb) print j 
$3 = 134518533
(gdb) next 
<some code for the next line to be executed by the **next** next command>
(gdb) print j 
$4 = 0
```